# Fink hangs with "IPC failure: Operation not permitted"

Tags: macos, fink

On OS X 10.7, I tried to install `enlightenment` via a fresh installation of Fink.

```
   cd /sw/bin
   ./fink install enlightenment
    Scanning package description files..........
```

Then nothing happens. Console shows the following error:

> org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub:
>   launch_msg("CheckIn") IPC failure: Operation not permitted

...

Then I after installing XQuartz... I got this :
could not determine XFree86 version number

Which might be fixed with the instructions from this blog: 
http://finkers.wordpress.com/2011/02/

http://finkers.wordpress.com/2011/02/

Comment: How long did you wait?  How many times did you try? Has Fink ever worked for you on this computer?

Comment: @techie007 I waited about 30 mins so far, I tried 4 times.  I ran init.sh and turned output up to maximum, after I did that I got the scanning pacakge message, before I didn't even get that.  I've never used Fink before on this machine.  I've never used Fink before now.

Comment: Any interesting messages printed in *Console.app*? Maybe try a `fink selfupdate` and then installing again.

Comment: @sihck good call on Console.app :  org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub: launch_msg("CheckIn") IPC failure: Operation not permitted

Comment: Did you install XQuartz correctly? Maybe try reinstalling from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/ — seems like a very rare issue though. (btw, it's sLhck, with an L ;)

Comment: @slhck I don't remember installing XQuartz, is it installed by default?

Comment: Well, you need this for GUI apps (scroll down on Fink's installation instructions). So, try installing X11 and then try again.